# Include CSRF token in requests in Vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin

On Vaadin's site they state that:

> All requests between the client and the server are included with a user session specific CSRF token

However, I'm unable to fetch this token programmatically. I tried `System.out.println(VaadinRequest.getCurrent().getAttribute("_csrf"));`

and

`System.out.println(VaadinRequest.getCurrent().getHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN"));`

In order to somehow see if the request really contains this token. In both cases, the returned value is `null`.

In my `SecurityConfig.java`, I have disabled the CSRF token, as the Vaadin breaks if it is enabled. I assume that there may be some overlap going on.

I also do have `SecurityVaadinConfig.java` which is pretty default, as it looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityVaadinConfig extends VaadinWebSecurity {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((auth) -> auth
                .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/**")).permitAll());
        super.configure(http);
        setLoginView(http, LoginView.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that this token is really passed in "all requests between the client and the server"?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I found this issue from 2 years ago (https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/issues/201). The CSRF token is passed as a meta tag of page. I was able to retrieve, and ensure myself that CSRF is enabled, CSRF token through `UI.getCurrent().getCsrfToken()`.